# LoadLibraryA with User32.dll crash in ntdll.dll (x64 assembly)

Tags: windows, assembly, crash, 64-bit

So I have a block of assembly code that initializes a program, resolves kernel32, finds GetProcAddress, then finds LoadLibarayA to load User32.dll. It works up to the point of LoadLibraryA. It crashes in the function call but I can see User32.dll loaded in the debugger. If I try to use LoadLibraryA on a different module such as Kernel32.dll it returns and succeeds.

Here is the full source if you want to look it over
https://gist.github.com/mojobojo/921a5af897e86bb940a2

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFAFAE8E91C (ntdll.dll) in Small.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.
```

Here is the snippet that trys to load user32.

```
    mov rcx, ActualAddress + User32DllStr ; ActualAddress is the program address in memory
    call rax ; LoadLibararyA
    cmp rax, 0
    je  EndFunction ; Failed to open user32.dll

LoadLibraryAStr:
    db "LoadLibraryA", 0
```

Here is a look at the call stack.

```
ntdll.dll!RtlDosPathNameToRelativeNtPathName()  Unknown
ntdll.dll!LdrpResolveDllName()  Unknown
ntdll.dll!LdrpFindLoadedDll()   Unknown
ntdll.dll!LdrGetDllHandleEx()   Unknown
ntdll.dll!LdrGetDllHandle() Unknown
KernelBase.dll!00007ffaf82d2984()   Unknown
KernelBase.dll!00007ffaf82d29ef()   Unknown
user32.dll!00007ffaf934e7e8()   Unknown
user32.dll!00007ffaf934dc92()   Unknown
ntdll.dll!LdrpCallInitRoutine() Unknown
ntdll.dll!LdrpInitializeNode()  Unknown
ntdll.dll!LdrpInitializeGraph() Unknown
ntdll.dll!LdrpPrepareModuleForExecution()   Unknown
ntdll.dll!LdrpLoadDll() Unknown
ntdll.dll!LdrLoadDll()  Unknown
KernelBase.dll!00007ffaf82d8e4a()   Unknown
KernelBase.dll!00007ffaf82d97e5()   Unknown
kernel32.dll!00007ffaf8b5499a() Unknown
Small.exe!0000000140010253()    Unknown
```

Comment: Double check that `rcx` indeed points to a valid zero terminated string at that time. That is put a breakpoint on that `call rax` and examine memory using the debugger.

Comment: I have confirmed the pointer is in the correct place and is null terminated.

Comment: Looks to me as though the DllMain in user32.dll is crashing while trying to reference another DLL.  Perhaps there's a prerequisite DLL you need to load first?

Comment: I am not sure. I uploaded the full source to a gist. Perhaps it has something to do with me overlapping the DOS and PE headers to get a smaller PE output? https://gist.github.com/mojobojo/921a5af897e86bb940a2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. My stack wasn't 16 byte aligned.